# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when a library accesses Validation.Errors

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, data-binding

This happens on my output when I change an invalid value to a valid one in a textbox:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'Item[]' value (type 'ValidationError') from '(Validation.Errors)' (type 'ReadOnlyObservableCollection`1'). BindingExpression:Path=AdornedElement.(0)[0].ErrorContent; DataItem='AdornedElementPlaceholder' (Name='adorner'); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') ArgumentOutOfRangeException:'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index'
```

After reading some similar questions on SO I know why this happens. Apparently one should set binding `Path` in the validation template to:

`Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent`

instead of:

`Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent`

to avoid accesing `[0]` element of an empty collection.

The problem is, however, that I haven't set any validation error templates. Most likely some library has set it for me. Is there any way to access the template and fix its binding `Path`? Or just anything to supress those exceptions but keep the template.

Either XAML or code-behind solution will do.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the FallbackValue property on the binding.